# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Hello this is problem which i can't overcome.

i do exact the same steps from jiri pinkas tutorial, and i have this exception:

> Hibernate: insert into Role (id, name) values (default, ?)
>   [WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@749ab7b4{/,file:/D:/Programowanie/workspace/java-blog-ggregator6/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:/D:/Programowanie/workspace/java-blog-ggregator6/src/main/webapp/}
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initDbService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:801)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:446)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:793)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:296)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1347)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:745)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:492)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:282)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:154)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:358)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:325)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:68)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:564)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:360)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:168)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:418)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:418)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.save(Unknown Source)
>       at com.jiripinkas.jba.service.InitDbService.init(InitDbService.java:40)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
>       ... 64 more
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:257)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.persist(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:369)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:358)
>       at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:343)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>       ... 79 more
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:122)
>       at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(IdentityGenerator.java:89)
>       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:55)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
>       at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:97)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:488)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:193)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:177)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:212)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
>       ... 98 more
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ROLE
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:124)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
>       ... 120 more
>   Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ROLE
>       at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readRangeVariableForDataChange(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
>       at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
>       ... 124 more
>       [WARNING] !RequestLog
>       [INFO] Started ServerConnector@7b8aebd0{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
>       [INFO] Started @10094ms
>       [INFO] Started Jetty Server

this is my InitDbService.class

```
   *packages
/////////////
@Service
public class InitDbService {

@Autowired
private RoleRepository roleRepository;

@Autowired
private BlogRepository blogRepository;

@Autowired
private ItemRepository itemRepository;

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    Role roleUser = new Role();
    roleRepository.save(roleUser);



    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                                 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"

version="3.0">
<display-name>java-blog-ggregator</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-  
class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>


</servlet-mapping>




<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-
class>    
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-    
class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> 




</web-app>
```

so on applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.jiripinkas.jba">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />


</context:component-scan>


<jdbc:embedded-database type="HSQL" id="dataSource" />

<bean

class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"   
id="emf">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.jiripinkas.jba.entity" />

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2dll.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="persistenceProvider">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"></bean>
    </property> 
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"   
id="transactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

</bean>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.jiripinkas.jba.repository">    
</jpa:repositories>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>java-blog-ggregator</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-  
class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>


</servlet-mapping>




<listener>
    <listener-
class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-
class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

Role.class

```
imports
//////

@Entity
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

private String name;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

RoleRepository.class

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer> {

}
```

Comment: I got this error please help that.